# Lightbox with navigation dropdown for wordpress site

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, lightbox

I've been looking through a lot of WP plugins for a Lightbox that I can use with a navigation dropdown and I'm lost.  What I'm looking to do is when someone clicks on "Stay" in the navigation (www.padreislandbeach.com) I need to have a lightbox pop up that then allows the user to select which location they would like more information about and allow them to select from one of three locations.  When they select that location, it should then take them to the "Stay" page for that location.  Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated!

The item I want this effect on is this:

```
<a href="http://www.padreislandbeach.com/where-to-stay-on-padre-island/">
    <img alt="" src="http://www.padreislandbeach.com/wp-content/themes/padreislandbeach/images/circle_stay.png">
</a>
```

I will then want them to be able to send them to one of the following links below:

```
<a href="http://www.padreislandbeach.com/what-to-do-south-padre/">

<a href="http://www.padreislandbeach.com/what-to-do-north-padre/">

<a href="http://www.padreislandbeach.com/what-to-do-port-aransas/">
```

These pages are not live at this point and are in draft mode

The location Options I want are "Port Aransas","North Padre","South Padre"

Comment: Please refrain from using a live link as that wont be useful to others with the same question down the road.  Add the code from your site that is relevant so we can help you!  Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Simply Craig.  I don't believe there is any relevant code at this point.

Comment: I suggested an edit, but I also suggest you add the urls to the pages you want those "Options" to link to, because it seems that those options are under just one page?  I can't find links to Location specific pages

Comment: Simply Craig I apologize but I can't figure out how to make the code show up correctly like you did...

Comment: You put 4 spaces before any code you want in the code block!  Not a problem, I suggested a fix for you! :)